# How to import node-menu package to my project instead of use require

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules

how can I import [node-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-menu) to my typescript project instead of using requiere, like this:

```
const menu = require('node-menu');
```

When I import [node-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-menu) to my project the next errors appears:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the `menu` probity from `node-menu` instead of the entire module. To fix this, change:

```js
import menu from 'node-menu';
```

to

```js
import * as menu from 'node-menu';
```